# Is it possible for the auto formatter to line up code using certain characters in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible for the auto formatter to line up code using certain characters in VS Code?

For example, turn this:

```
{
    "one" : "one",
    "two" : "two",
    "three" : "three",
    "four" : "four"
}
```

Into this:

```
{
    "one"   : "one",
    "two"   : "two",
    "three" : "three",
    "four"  : "four"
}
```

Or this:

```
var one = "one";
var two = "two";
var three = "three";
var four = "four";
```

Into this:

```
var one   = "one";
var two   = "two";
var three = "three";
var four  = "four";
```

Comment: Depends on the formatter. You'll have to configure whatever VS Code is using to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this language-agnostically would be to use the [Cursor Align](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yo1dog.cursor-align) extension, and use multiple cursors. To align a set of characters, you can select all occurrences of the selection (on Windows, the keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+L)

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks. Will leave this unanswered for a bit to see if anyone knows of an automatic way to do this. If not, I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: This works great but then on file save it re-formats using the formatter configuration. I need to find a way to tell the formatter not to trim spaces in certain places. :/ Thanks!